# Can I change limit_up speed?

Tags: full-node, nodes, network

Default is 2047 kB/s. If I am able to increase this, would it be advantageous for the network? If I were to increase it, what would be a good number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change them, either when starting monerod:

  `--limit-rate-up arg (=-1)             set limit-rate-up [kB/s]
  --limit-rate-down arg (=-1)           set limit-rate-down [kB/s]
  --limit-rate arg (=-1)                set limit-rate [kB/s]`

Or at runtime:

  `limit                   limit <kB/s> - Set download and upload limit
  limit_down              limit <kB/s> - Set download limit
  limit_up                limit <kB/s> - Set upload limit`

Which settings are best is really down to your own connection speeds. You'll want to set something that's below your max speed, so your normal Internet use doesn't get wedged.

More bandwidth is advantageous for the network, as it means you can exchange historical blocks after, allowing peers to get up to speed more quickly. Make sure you have incoming connections working (ie, setup port forwarding on your router as appropriate, and check that the monerod `status` command gives you a X+Y connections where both X and Y are greater than zero).

Comment: Hmmm but no matter what I enter it says the command is unknown!

Comment: That's most likely because you enter the wrong thing in the wrong place. But since you did not give any details, you'll have to work it out alone.

Comment: Yeah. I was able to figure it out.